# MGO/GOLANG: Struct to unmarshall a document with

Tags: struct, go, mgo

I have a Mongo schema that looks like this:

```
  var phoneBookSchema = Schema({

      user_id: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'User',
          index: {
              unique : true
          },
          required: true
      },

      entries: {
          type: [entry],
          default: []
      },

      matches: {
          type: [],
          default: []
      }

  });
```

The array of entry documents looks like this:

```
  var entry = Schema({

        _id : false,

        phone: {
              type: String,
              index: true
        },

        name: {
              type: String
        },

        notified: {
              type: Boolean,
              default: false,
              required: true
        }

  });
```

How do I format the PhoneBook struct in Golang so that I can run a query like this and unmarshall the results into an array of PhoneBooks?

```
  var results []PhoneBook

  err = pb.Find(bson.M{}).All(&results)
```

Comment: Have you tried something on your own you could show? That would make it easier to support you.

Comment: @Sebastian thanks for getting back to me, I figured it out though and posted the results below

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, here is the answer for anyone who might find it useful.

```
type PhoneBook struct {
    User_id bson.ObjectId
    Entries []Entry
    Matches []User
}

type Entry struct {
    Phone string
    Name string
    Notified bool
}

type User struct {
    User_id string
    Username string
}
```

Comment: Nice to see you figured it out. You can also annotate the fields of your structs to ensure the name matches exactly with your database schema. Otherwise you might run into issues when storing data.

Comment: Indeed. User_id is not a conventional name for a field in Go. Instead, you can use `UserId \`bson:"user_id"\``